# Can you register a Web API ActionFilter without doing it globally?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have seen how to do this globally in numerous posts and have it working in my code.  The problem is that it's firing on EVERY call which isn't what I want, I only want it to fire on the calls to the methods where I have decorated the method with the attribute:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public void MethodA()
    {
        // Do Work - should have called the attribute filter
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        // Do Work - should NOT have called the attribute filter
    }
}
```

This seems really basic to me and that I'm missing something but the only way I can get the attribute to fire at all is by registering it in `global.asax` using `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MyAttribute());` which causes it to fire on requests to both `MethodA` and `MethodB`.  Is there any way to register the attribute and only fire on the methods where it is tagged?  I have tried using `AttributeUsage` to no avail.

**EDIT** Added code for attribute per comment although had to remove the inner workings.  It's firing on all requests...

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

**Edit 11/25**
In addition to the information below where I accepted the answer I would like to add that a previous developer had removed the default ActionDescriptorFilterProvider with the following code that needed to be commented out in order for the default behavior of the custom action filters to take effect:

```
var providers = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders();
var defaultprovider = providers.First(i => i is ActionDescriptorFilterProvider);

// This line was causing the problem.    
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Remove(typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider), defaultprovider);
```

Comment: What is MyClass here?...yes, you can decorate filter attributes on actions of a controller and only those would get invoked as you are expecting, but i see that here MyClass isn't a controller...

Comment: you should show the source for your attribute as well

Comment: It is an ApiController, updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: @Dan-o added code for the action filter.

Comment: @Kiran Challa yes, that's the way it worked in MVC 3, this is MVC 4 with a WebAPI controller and I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to work quite the same way.

Comment: not sure what you are doing wrong - may be your "stripped" code does not have the error you have in your live code - but I have exactly the same case in one of my projects - and it works just fine. WebAPI + custom attribute inherited from ActionFilterAttribute and attached only to 1 action in my controller - and it works just fine. Check your code - or create the simplest compilable solution which reproduces the issue and upload it somewhere so we can check. Thx

Comment: @avs099 how are you registering the filter?

Comment: posted my answer - I did not realize you register your filter in Global.asax file and I don't do that :)

Comment: Hi I have the same problem, so what's the solution? I did not quite get it pls

Comment: @AndySong the solution is in my Edit from 11/25.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see [HttpConfiguration.Filters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.Filters%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) - it clearly says

> Gets the list of filters that **apply to all requests** served using this
>   HttpConfiguration instance.

but you need ActionFilter - which is, by definition,

> Action filters contain logic that is executed before and after a
>   controller action executes. You can use an action filter, for
>   instance, to modify the view data that a controller action returns.

so basically what you need to do is to **remove**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MyAttribute());
```

line from your Global.asax.cs file.

Comment: Hmmm, well, this is close to providing me with an answer.  I see that this is the case with how it works on my OOB sample project.  I'll take a deeper look at the interactions of our filters with the registration handler and report back.  If it gets me the solution, I will mark this as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using filter on the Action or Controller level you need to register it in the same ConfigureServices method but as a service:

```
services.AddScoped<ActionFilterExample>();
services.AddScoped<ControllerFilterExample>();
```

Finally, to use a filter registered on the Action or Controller level, you need to place it on top of the Controller or Action as a ServiceType:

```
namespace AspNetCore.Controllers
{
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(ControllerFilterExample))]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ServiceFilter(typeof(ActionFilterExample))]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "example", "data" };
        }
    }
}
```